# Signed Jar giving unsigned error through web start

Tags: java, glassfish, java-web-start, jarsigner

Title says it all really. I have now managed to build and deploy my ear file which contains a EJB, war and appclient project. I have the jnlp file pointing to the right place and I have signed the Appclient jar file.

Its [here](http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeWeb/maze/Home/howto) if you want to look. The error states unsigned jars but there is only one jar as I used [jarsplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) on it. Can anyone tell me how to fix this final problem?

Direct link to jnlp [here](http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeWeb/res/mazeApp.jnlp) Contents of jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp" href="http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeWeb/res/mazeApp.jnlp">
    <information>
         <title>Maze Runner</title>
         <vendor>Vendor</vendor>
     </information>
      <security>
        <all-permissions/>
      </security>

      <resources>
      <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="mazeAppClient.jar"  main="true"/>
        <jar href="lib/jME3-core.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jME3-desktop.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jME3-plugins.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jME3-effects.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jME3-networking.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jME3-jogg.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/j-ogg-oggd.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/j-ogg-vorbisd.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jME3-terrain.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jME3-lwjgl.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jME3-lwjgl-natives.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jinput.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/lwjgl.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jME3-jbullet.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jbullet.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/vecmath.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/stack-alloc.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jME3-niftygui.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/nifty.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/nifty-default-controls.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/nifty-style-black.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/eventbus.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/xmlpull-xpp3.jar" />
        <jar href="lib/jME3-testdata.jar" />
    </resources>
 <application-desc main-class="Main"></application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Lay out of ear file is:

```
mazeApp ear:   
    |- lib
        |- Jmonkey libs   
    |- META-INF   
    |- mazeAppClient.jar   
    |- mazeEjb.jar   
    |- mazeWeb.war
```

3rd party libs in their own directory and referenced as resources in the jnlp. They are all self signed.

Currently I am still getting an unsigned error but I think it is because none of the resources are found. If I load the jnlp from the page (localhost) I get unsigned error but if I run the jnlp from javaws I can see that all files are not found before the unsigned error is raised.

[edit-update] Is this a configuration issue as it just seems that the path mazeApp/MazeAppClent just isn't there or visible?

[edit-update] altering the path for my main jar file to `<jar href="mazeAppClient/mazeAppClient.jar"  main="true"/>`seems to allow it to be found i.e. it is no longer included in the not found list. However applying the same change to the other jars, in lib dir, does not have the same affect.

JaNeLa report for url in jnlp shown above

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


Report for http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeWeb/res/mazeApp.jnlp

XML encoding not known, but declared as UTF-8
Optimize this application for off-line use by adding the <offline-allowed /> flag.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'mazeAppClient.jar'.
The resource download at mazeAppClient.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for mazeAppClient.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-core.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-core.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-core.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-core.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-core.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-desktop.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-desktop.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-desktop.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-desktop.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-desktop.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-plugins.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-plugins.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-plugins.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-plugins.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-plugins.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-effects.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-effects.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-effects.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-effects.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-effects.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-networking.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-networking.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-networking.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-networking.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-networking.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-jogg.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-jogg.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-jogg.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-jogg.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-jogg.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/j-ogg-oggd.jar'.
The resource download at lib/j-ogg-oggd.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/j-ogg-oggd.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/j-ogg-oggd.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/j-ogg-oggd.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/j-ogg-vorbisd.jar'.
The resource download at lib/j-ogg-vorbisd.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/j-ogg-vorbisd.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/j-ogg-vorbisd.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/j-ogg-vorbisd.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-terrain.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-terrain.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-terrain.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-terrain.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-terrain.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-lwjgl.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-lwjgl.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-lwjgl.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-lwjgl.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-lwjgl.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-lwjgl-natives.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-lwjgl-natives.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-lwjgl-natives.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-lwjgl-natives.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-lwjgl-natives.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jinput.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jinput.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jinput.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jinput.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jinput.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/lwjgl.jar'.
The resource download at lib/lwjgl.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/lwjgl.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/lwjgl.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/lwjgl.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-jbullet.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-jbullet.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-jbullet.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-jbullet.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-jbullet.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jbullet.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jbullet.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jbullet.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jbullet.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jbullet.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/vecmath.jar'.
The resource download at lib/vecmath.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/vecmath.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/vecmath.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/vecmath.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/stack-alloc.jar'.
The resource download at lib/stack-alloc.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/stack-alloc.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/stack-alloc.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/stack-alloc.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-niftygui.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-niftygui.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-niftygui.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-niftygui.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-niftygui.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/nifty.jar'.
The resource download at lib/nifty.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/nifty.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/nifty.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/nifty.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/nifty-default-controls.jar'.
The resource download at lib/nifty-default-controls.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/nifty-default-controls.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/nifty-default-controls.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/nifty-default-controls.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/nifty-style-black.jar'.
The resource download at lib/nifty-style-black.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/nifty-style-black.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/nifty-style-black.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/nifty-style-black.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/eventbus.jar'.
The resource download at lib/eventbus.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/eventbus.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/eventbus.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/eventbus.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/xmlpull-xpp3.jar'.
The resource download at lib/xmlpull-xpp3.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/xmlpull-xpp3.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/xmlpull-xpp3.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/xmlpull-xpp3.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/jME3-testdata.jar'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-testdata.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/jME3-testdata.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/jME3-testdata.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jME3-testdata.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
```

This is the output I get if I run javaws

```
javaws  http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeWeb/res/mazeApp.jnlp
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/mazeAppClient.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-core.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-desktop.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-plugins.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-effects.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-networking.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-jogg.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/j-ogg-oggd.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/j-ogg-vorbisd.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-terrain.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-lwjgl.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-lwjgl-natives.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jinput.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/lwjgl.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-jbullet.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jbullet.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/vecmath.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/stack-alloc.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-niftygui.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/nifty.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/nifty-default-controls.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/nifty-style-black.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/eventbus.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/xmlpull-xpp3.jar not found. Continuing.
JAR http://www.mazerunner.co.uk/mazeApp/lib/jME3-testdata.jar not found. Continuing.
netx: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. (Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.)
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. 
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:797)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:555)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:908)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:319)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:239)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:381)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:337)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:789)
    ... 2 more
```

Note if I amend the first jar to include mazeAppClient/mazeAppCLient.jar it seems to find it but the same does not work for the other jar files.

Clicking the launch button from the site I get

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. 
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:797)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:555)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:908)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:319)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:239)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:381)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:337)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:789)
    ... 2 more
```

I have signed the jars so do I get that error because they have not been downloaded?
[edit-update] I have just got a fileIOException from the live site so it can't find the app with that url

Comment: Are you including third party jars? If so they need to be signed too.  Some of them cannot be signed because they already are which would lead to more errors.  It'll take time for me to find the solution I've done before but it essentially means creating a separate jnlp file that is used by the main one for any of the libraries.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Basically it uses jmonkey but the libs aren't separate any more but I don't suppose that makes any difference. I would really appreciate seeing that fix you mentioned

Comment: `http://www.mazerunner.co.uk:8080/mazeApp/mazeAppClient.jar` -> 404.  BTW - I got a `NullPointerException` as opposed to that an 'unsigned' error.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I can't get that error I only get the signed error. I have now signed all the JMonkey jars by adding my signature to them. This worked running javaws <jnlp name> for loading the applicaiton. When I then added it to my ear file and deployed it to my local machine I still get the not signed error.

Comment: It seems that my signing error is related to not finding the jars in the first place. When I do this with javaws now I get not found for all my jars including my own and then the signing error.

Comment: I have noticed that the port number is missing from the download urls

Comment: *"I can't get that error"*  I got that 404 b visiting that link, going through some shenanigans, finding the URL of the JNLP, downloading it and inspecting it for the location of the Jar, then inputting the resulting URL into a browser.  Please save me the trouble of doing that by 1) posting a link direct to the JNLP. 2) Copy/pasting the content of the JNLP into the question.

Comment: Done that for you @Andrew Thompson. By the way I have seen you mention Janela in a few posts but the links seem to be dead.

Comment: My apologies about that.  That (and several other) of my sites disappeared because the free host gave up hosting a little time ago. For the moment, you can get it from my Google [share drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thanks and now I get the nullPointerException you mentioned.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Report is telling me connection refused but I am at work and think that is the issue as I can't get to the sites main page from here. Will use it later at home.

Comment: 1) The `codebase` of the JNLP posted in the question would only work for you.  Change it back to `http://www.mazerunner.co.uk:8080/mazeApp/`2) With that code base and `href` for `jME3-testdata.jar` would prompt the JVM to look load it from `http://www.mazerunner.co.uk:8080/mazeApp/lib/jME3-testdata.jar` but that is also a 404..  But JaNeLA can tell you these sorts of things faster/better than I can.  ;)

Comment: yes and I think I have a problem with the port on my server although I can access it from home fine I get connection errors from work so I think this is adding to my problem. However even on localhost I get the message "not found" for all the jars in lib (and mazeAppClient as shown above) As far as I can make out they are placed correctly but still can't be found. I am getting very confused. :(

Comment: What does JaNeLA report?  Copy/paste it.

Comment: The only output I can get from the live url is NullPointerException have pasted report from file on c:\ but not sure how much use that is. I will update it later from hoe when I can access the site.

Comment: Ok at home now and JaNeLa report posted. I have updated the jnlp contents to what I have just uploaded as I made some edits based on an earlier report. Name not allowed in <Application-desc> and I removed  <update check="background"/> as it said something about that also.